# Mule Properties in a java component

Tags: java, properties, mule

In my **Mule** project, I have a property file that contains my http address for instance 
     `server.address = http://localhost:8080/test/`
and then in my flow i will reference it as `${server.address}` , but how do i reference that property in a java component class?

For instance:

```
  public String address = ${server.address}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load that property or any other property, loading the properties file. (although it could create some performance issues, loading the properties file every time the flow is executed).

```
public Properties loadProperties(String name) {
    if(properties == null){
        return loadProperties(name, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
    } else {
        return properties;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
Properties props = loadProperties("application.properties");
String url = props.getProperty("server.address");
```

Making some changes to @Matt answer

```
    import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
    import org.mule.api.MuleEventContext;
    import org.mule.api.lifecycle.Callable;   

    public class MyClass implements Callable {
       private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class);
       private String server;
       private Properties properties;

       public MyClass() {  }

       @Override
       public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {
           properties = loadProperties("application.properties");
           server = properties.getProperty("server.address");
           logger.info("Server is " + server);
           return null;
       }

       public Properties loadProperties(String name) {
            if(properties == null){
                return loadProperties(name, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
            } else {
               return properties;
            }
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can set the property in your java class as a Spring property.  For a singleton object, the property would be set when the flow is started.

```
<flow name="propertyprojectFlow1" doc:name="propertyprojectFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8581" path="echoServer" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <component  doc:name="Java">
        <singleton-object class="MyClass">
            <property key="server" value="${server.address}"/>
        </singleton-object>
    </component>
</flow>
```

The class would need to have a setter for the property.

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.mule.api.MuleEventContext;
import org.mule.api.lifecycle.Callable;


public class MyClass implements Callable {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class);
    private String server;

    public MyClass() {
    }

    @Override
    public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {
        logger.info("Server is " + server);
        return null;
    }

    public void setServer(String server) {
        logger.info("Setting server to " + server);
        this.server = server;
    }

}
```

Comment: if i want to set the proper key value to a variable? like for instance: <property key="originalFileName" value ="#[flowVars['FileName']]"/> but the class is reading it as a string "#[flowVars['FileName']]" and not the value of the varaible

Answer (score 3):

Property name in properties file:

```
your.property.name.in.properties.file=testing
```

Java component:

```
import org.mule.api.MuleEventContext;
import org.mule.api.lifecycle.Callable;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

public class PropertyTest implements Callable {

    @Value("${your.property.name.in.properties.file}")
    private String yourPropertyNameInPropertiesFile;

    @Override
    public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("yourPropertyNameInPropertiesFile"+yourPropertyNameInPropertiesFile);

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```